# doctrine-extensions Uploadable, how to use in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: upload, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-extensions

I integrated doctrine-extensions in my project. Timestampable is working as example. But how to use the "Uploadable"-behavior?

I read this [doc](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md). They're writing in the [usage-part](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md#additional-usages) about using `$listener`, but how do i get this variable? in my Controller or Service? Where does it come from?

thanks for any advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got it...:

**instead of:**

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'subscribers' => array(
                'Gedmo\Uploadable\UploadableListener',
                //...
            ),
        ),
    ),
   'driver' => array(
        // ...
    ),
),
```

**use this:** register the uploadable listener through the servicemanager:

```
    'doctrine' => array(
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'subscribers' => array(
                'doctrine_extensions.uploadable',
                //...
            ),
        ),
    ),
   'driver' => array(
        // ...
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'doctrine_extensions.uploadable'    => 'Gedmo\Uploadable\UploadableListener'
    )
),
```

then in the controller as example, it works like this:

```
$uploadManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine_extensions.uploadable');
foreach($this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray() as $file) {
    $entity = new MyEntity();
    $uploadManager->addEntityFileInfo($entity, $file);

    // persist($entity) ...
}
```